# Doxygen: how to make an entire file "Internal"?

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I want to make an entire page of my documentation 'Internal' so that it is only generated when `INTERNAL_DOCS = YES`.  I'm using markdown format for the bulk text of this document, so all these files are **.md** extension, not that that should make a difference.

If I apply this within an `@page` *part* of a source text file the following works as expected, in that all evidence of the page disappears from the output:

```
@internal
@page hidden_page Blah Blah
Text is here.    
@endinternal
```

However, some of my pages are quite long and I've factored them out to a separate file.

```
# Page Title

Extensive text here.
```

The first-line markdown title stops Doxygen using the filename for the title of the page.

**The problem is**, if I do this...

```
@internal
# Page Title

Extensive text here.
@endinternal
```

The text *body* is duly hidden, but the (blank) page still exists in the output, showing the filename as the page title.

Reversing the order of the top lines makes no real difference - it just means the blank page is titled differently.

I can't find anything in the relevant parts of the Doxygen manual.  I'm using 1.8.5.

One, undesirable, solution is to 'unfactor' the separated page(s) back into a page that is always visible and use the technique described at the top.  However, there are quite a number of such pages.

Does anyone know how whole files can be made completely internal, or have any other approaches that may work for this?

Answer (score 2):

I've not had a lot of success with using @internal where pages are concerned so the method I have had success with is using @if along with ENABLED_SECTIONS, see [Doxygen if command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdif). I've tested the following out with python files and although this does generate a couple of warnings it does what I think you need.

```
## @if COND1
# @file cond_file.py Conditional File
#
# Conditional documentation.
#
# @page conditional_page Conditional Page
#
# This page will only exist if COND1 is set.
#
# @endif
```

The if you want the section included in your documentation simply add the following to the doxygen config file:

```
ENABLED_SECTIONS = COND1
```

Comment: It's a reasonable approach, so +1 and thanks for looking at this older question.  However, having tried it, I'm still getting the blank page being generated which is what I was getting with `@internal`. It's possible Doxygen is handling Markdown and Python differently in this respect.  What I'm ideally looking for is the complete absence of the markdown page if it 'compiles' to nothing.

Comment: +bounty. This isn't a full solution but I appreciate the contribution; and it's more than anyone else has provided, so thanks.